# Check/uncheck all switches Android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a problem with a listview and switches that I have to add another switch that checks or unchecks the others.

My class:

```
data class Student(
        @PrimaryKey
        val idStudent: String,
        val name: String
)
```

Then I have a listview that's binding the data that I have:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 ">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerStudent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</FrameLayout>
```

I also created a viewholder for the adapter:

```
class StudPrefViewHolder(inflater: LayoutInflater, parent: ViewGroup) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_single_switch, parent, false)) {
    private var mSwitch: Switch? = null

    init {
        mSwitch = itemView.findViewById(R.id.switchStud)
    }

    fun bind(stu: Student){
        mSwitch?.text = stu.name
    }

}
```

And of course another class that contains the adapter:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: StudPrefViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val stu: Student = list[position]
    holder.bind(stu)
    val switch = holder.itemView.switchStu

}
```

The objective is to set at checked the whole list of my students by one switch.
someone has an idea please?
I tried to add a switch.setOnchecked, using the position, I could access to it but the problem is that I couldn't found the method to switch to check the others.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a field call checked in your Student class:

```
data class Student(
        @PrimaryKey
        val idStudent: String,
        val name: String,
        var checked: Boolean = False
)
```

And in your bind function

```
fun bind(stu: Student){
        mSwitch?.text = stu.name
        mSwitch.checked = stu.checked
    }
```

if you want to check all item in list just update the field checked each item.
After that, update list of adapter and notify data change, and each item will check or uncheck according the field checked in Student class in bind function.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I did that and added just another class because I couldn't use the same due to Room library.